# How do I edit an AWS S3 Bucket Object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web

I followed Amazon's instructions for hosting a static webpage:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/website-hosting-intro.html

Now I want to update that static webpage, what are the various ways to do that?

- Is there a sync client?
- Can I open the files on AWS somehow?
- Do I need to download the file, edit it, and re-upload it?

Comment: When answering your own question, please create an answer instead of adding an 'edit' to your original question.

Comment: I cannot add answers, but I added a comment to @Max's answer

Comment: Check out [S3ditor][1] .You just need to enable CORS on the Bucket &  Access Key for it. Tested on Mozilla


  [1]: http://sagarmhatre.github.io/s3ditor/

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
echo Welcome to S3 bucket editor.\ Please enter the remote s3 bucket unique name:

read bucket_name

echo OK.

echo Enter the path to \local directory:

read local_directory

echo Details:\ s3 bucket:  s3://$bucket_name \ \local directory: $local_directory

read -p "Press {Enter} to continue"

sed -i -e "s/export BUCKET_NAME.*/export BUCKET_NAME=$bucket_name/" .bashrc
sed -i -e "s/export LOCAL_DIRECTORY.*/export LOCAL_DIRECTORY=$local_directory/" .bashrc

aws s3 sync s3://$bucket_name $local_directory
. .bashrc
$EDITOR $local_directory` **use this bash script**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to update a file is to overwrite it. You can use the [CLI sync client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) or use a GUI (search Google).

You currently cannot open the files in AWS to edit.

You don't have to download a file if its already downloaded :). So if you edit a file, upload, edit again, upload again, etc., no need for downloading.

Comment: This is the command I ended up needing after installing Amazon CLI

aws s3 sync ~/local/website/path s3://mybucketname --delete --acl public-read

That does a full copy of the website from my local copy to the S3 bucket and it also makes the website public (make sure this is what you want!)

To get the original copy I needed to do this:

aws s3 sync s3://mybucketname ~/local/website/path